# Are my hibernate enums working properly/stable setup?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have some properties that are enumerations like on my User object:

```
@Column(name = "user_status")
private UserStatus userStatus;
```

Where UserStatus is:

```
public enum UserStatus {
    NONE(0),
    MEMBER(1),
    PENDING(2);

    private long enumValue;

    UserStatus(long permissionValue) {
        this.enumValue = permissionValue;
    }

    public long getEnumValue() {
        return enumValue;
    }

    public void setEnumValue(long enumValue) {
        this.enumValue = enumValue;
    }
}
```

In the database (mysql) the UserStatus column is:

```
user_status int(11) NOT NULL
```

I'm confused, how is this working?  Is hibernate smart enough to map this?

Answer (score 1):

The JPA specification defines the behavior of embedded enums, allowing for their storage as either an integer based ordinal, or as a string representation. The default behavior is to store enums as integer ordinals. You can control this behavior via the `@Enumerated` annotation. In your example, the following would cause your JPA provider to generate a varchar type in your DDL:

```
@Column(name = "user_status")
@Enumerated(STRING)
private UserStatus userStatus;
```

As a side note, its a horrible idea in my opinion to store integer ordinals in the database, as the data becomes garbage if you reorder/change the enum members.

Reference: [JPA 2.0 Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf) - Section 11.1.16

Comment: I see, but in my above code, I am explicitly setting the value, so I can control it right? i.e. will me setting the value help somewhat?

Comment: Well, you're setting ***a*** value. It's for an attribute you added though, not one that JPA will know about.